# If the asker does not like editing, can we do anything else?

Tags: discussion

If a question is edited (or suggested edit otherwise) for betterment of understanding or formatting or anything else, and the asker does not like it and turn it down (or better say roll back) after reviewing, despite the edited one being good, is there anyway we can pursue him edit the question himself or by others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a situation where the mods must step in and make a decision about the edit.  If the either the edit or the original are better, there are ways, I believe, that we can lock a post so that no more edits or rollbacks can occur.

Going back and forth in an edit war with a post is ***NOT*** recommended.

If you have an edit that is rolled back by either the OP or someone else, especially if there is no comment as to why, then flag the post for a moderator to review (Flag -> It Needs Moderator Attention -> Other -> Explain why it is being flagged) and we will discuss among ourselves what to do with the post.

Comment: Thanks @tyler for your wonderful answer.

Comment: Anytime :D :D :D